# Probleme reinstalling Qgiscloud after installation Qgis 2.18

Tags: qgis, plugins, qgis-cloud

After installation Qgis 2.18 I try to reinstall Qgiscloud, I get the message :

```
ImportError: No module named openlayers_plugin.openlayers_layer 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 342, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/Pierre/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugin.py", line 73, in initGui
    self.dockWidget = QgisCloudPluginDialog(self.iface, self.version)
  File "C:/Users/Pierre/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 171, in __init__
    from openlayers_menu import OpenlayersMenu
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Pierre/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgiscloud\openlayers_menu.py", line 27, in 
    from openlayers_plugin.openlayers_layer import OpenlayersLayer
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named openlayers_plugin.openlayers_layer
```

I try everything to repair but do not find the solution.

Comment: did you tried to first install the openlayer plugin and then add the QGISCloud plugin?

Comment: to me, after looking into the source code on https://github.com/qgiscloud/qgis-cloud-plugin, it seems that modules are missing. Namely openlayers_plugin in "from openlayers_plugin.openlayers_layer import OpenlayersLayer" does not exist. A dependency for the openlayers plugin can not be found either.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade the plugin from the official plugin repository. The issue is fixed with this release.

Answer (score 1):

It works today after creating a new account on the qgis cloud site and installing first the openlayer plugin before the qgiscloud plugin. 
Thank you for help!